# Nginx configuration on Centos

Tags: nginx, centos7

I have purchased New VPS from weloveservers provider . My VPS operating system is Centos 7 . My allocated IP is 192.3.108.207 . I have installed Nginx using ssh . Now i need to show something on my IP address . How can i point my IP to specific folder .. My current configuration for nginx is as follows ,

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

}

Here is my virtual.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  192.3.108.207;
    root   /var/www;

   #charset koi8-r;
   #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

   location / {
      root   /var/www;
      index  index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the particular folder in your virtual.conf.
As you have mentioned in your virtual.conf root /var/www;

Instead of /var/www; , you can give the folder name and restart your nginx service.